# VSTO Excel Add-in only working for one user account (user that developed it)

Tags: c#, certificate, vsto, installshield, excel-addins

I recently developed a C# excel add-in in visual studio 2015. I tried deploying it two different ways onto a server where a few different users will be accessing it. I tried a click-once deployment as well as an installshield package. Both ways yielded the same results.

Basically what happens is that, when I login with my user account (the account that I developed the add-in under, and also who the certificate is for, just whatever the default free thing is in visual studio) it works fine (it just has NPOI read the spreadsheet, does a few calculations). However when I login as a different user I can still see the add-in but nothing happens. When I click on the button it doesn't even attempt to run the code. I have logging setup as the very first step and nothing happens, just ignores it.

Has anyone ever encountered this or have an idea of what the issue may be? I'm really frustrated and at first I thought it was due to installing the app for only local users via clickonce, but with the installshield deployment I verified that the correct values are being added to the local_machine registry directories.

Comment: No error messages?  Have you looked in the event log (I have no idea if something would show up there, but that's a good place to leave a "hey, nothing is working" message)

Comment: @flydog57 Nope, nothing in the event log. It's so weird. No error messages whatsoever. You just click on it and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging